# How to add to an ArrayList that is a HashMap value while iterating?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, hashmap, big-o

I have a HashMap and the key's value is an ArrayList. As I read a file line by line I need to add to the ArrayList that belongs to that specific key.
The file may have 1 line or 1 million lines, the key name will be the line (String) and it's value will represent the line number that it occurs on in the file.

Can someone help me out? Also, is this fast time-complexity wise? How can I optimize this if it isn't?

Example test.txt:

```
Hello        <== Line 0
Jello        <== Line 1
Mello        <== Line 2
Hello        <== Line 3
Tello        <== Line 4
Jello        <== Line 5
Tello        <== Line 6
Tello        <== Line 7
```

What I need my map to store (ignore order):

```
{"Hello": [0, 3]}
{"Jello": [1, 5]}
{"Mello": [2]}
{"Tello": [4, 6, 7]}
```

My code is:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();

int num = 0;
for (String line = file.readLine(); line != null; line = file.readLine()) {
    map.put(line, al.add(num)); <== the issue is here, how to fix?
}
```

compiler error:

```
incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>
```

Comment: Call `al.add(num);` as a separate statement, then use `map.put(line, num);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add function of ArrayList returns a boolean that represents success or failure. This is why you are getting the error. You will have to add you number to the list first and then put the list in the map. But there is a different problem in your code. You will be adding the same list over and over to all the keys.

Try this code:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
int currentLineNumber = 0;
for (String line = file.readLine(); line != null; line = file.readLine()) {

    if(!hm.containsKey(line))
    {
        hm.put(line, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    hm.get(line).add(currentLineNumber);

    currentLineNumber++;
}
```

Comment: The add method for arraylist will always return true, but that's kind of nitpicking. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)

Comment: It will. But the meaning of the boolean comes from the underlying collection https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)

Answer (score 4):

Java 8:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(line, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(num);
```

Java 7:

```
ArrayList<Integer> values = map.get(line);
if (values == null) {
    map.put(line, values = new ArrayList<>());
}
values.add(num);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The length of the lists were correct, however its elements would always be 0.

Comment: @udpcon just values.add(num++)

Comment: @udpcon You have to increment `num` obviously. That wasn't the question.

Comment: This answer is actually better tbh. The Java 8 part.

Comment: My bad, stupid me. I really liked this answer. I liked both. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `add` method on array lists returns a boolean.

You are trying to do a "concordance" application and it is pretty easy to do a web search for a solution to this in Java. The other answers to this question do a good job of illustrating it.

As to your complexity question, using a hash map whose keys are words and whose values are array lists of line numbers is perfectly fine (and should have near optimal complexity, as each line process takes amortized constant time). This is the case, however, as long as everything fits in memory! If your file of words gets into the gazillions, you can do your concordance with a good map-reduce framework, using intermediate files.

Comment: This was a gret explanation. I'm glad I thought it out right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is adding integers to the HashMap key instead of the whole ArrayList

Try something like this:

```
            Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();

            String key="";
            while(file.readLine()!=null){
              key=file.readLine();  
      ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

          OUT: for (String line = file.readLine(); line != null; line = file.readLine()) { 
if(key.equals(line)){
              al.add(num);
  }
    else{
     break OUT;
}
}
             map.put(key, al);
        }
```

This solution is not been tested but I think this will work.

Comment: This does not look like it will compile.

Comment: i forgot to add a closing bracket in while.. i corrected that..try now

Comment: No i meant the "key=line". line is only scoped to the for loop.

Comment: sorry for that.. please check now.. updated my answer

Comment: This will compile but the logic is flawed. Remember the file in the while loop is the same file in the for loop. So the for loop will eventually read the file to the end which means the while loop is not required. Also remember that you are always adding to the same array list. So you will have one list with all the numbers in it eventually. But you basic idea is correct where you want to first build the list and then add it.

Comment: This will still give the same error in the original question though. Adding a boolean to something that wants an ArrayList.

Comment: Yes this is much closer to working correctly. But I still suspect some wrong behaviour with the same file being read in both loops. The readLine() will move the file cursor. You can correct me if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134147/discussion-between-shahid-sarwar-and-reasurria).

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer num = 0;
for (String line = file.readLine(); line != null; line = file.readLine()) {

    if(!hm.containsKey(line))
    {
        hm.put(line, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    hm.get(line).add(num);

    num++;
}
```

i think this should work.